# XAMPP Server is not being executing after installation complete

Tags: php, xampp

I have installed XAMPP Server on Windows Multipoint Server 12. After the installation is completed, the control panel is not being executed. Whenever I try to execute it I am given error messages:

> Runtime error 217 at 004225BE

What is wrong with installing XAMPP on this Windows? I have installed XAMPP on my laptop hundreds of time but this is my first attempt to do so on a server Windows.

Answer (score 0):

That problem may cause by port 80 is already in used. So you have to configure httpd.conf and change the listen port 80 to 81.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an old thread but my answer may help someone who got the same error.

My OS is also Windows Multipoint Server 12 and the error has occurred when I trying to run xampp-control.exe.

To solve that problem, right click the `xampp-control.exe`, select `properties`, select `Compatibility` Tab, under compatibility mode check `"run this program in compatibility mode for"` then select `windows Xp (Service Pack 3)`. then ok. Try to run the xampp-control.exe again and the error will never appear again.